# Python app deployment using nginx and dockerize flask app

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I would like to deploy flask app on my VPS. I figured out easy how to do it without docker, but now I dockerized the app and I am running it using docker-composer.yml.

```
services:                                                                      │
  myapp:                                                           │
    build: ./myapp                                          │
    container_name: myapp                                         │
    restart: always                                                            │
    environment:                                                               │
      - APP_NAME = myapp                                          │
    expose:                                                                    │
      - 8081
```

So I changed my nginx conf
from

```
   location / {
         include    uwsgi_params;
         uwsgi_pass unix:/home/username/path/to/socket/mysocker.sock;
     }
```

to

```
 location / {
     include    uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_pass myapp:8081;
 }
```

The app is running using docker composer but when I test the correct settings in nginx using nginx -t I get this message

> nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "myapp" in
> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myapp:22
> │nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

I am pretty sure that means that nginx cannot find myapp running in docker and cannot communicate with it but I exposed the port and from what I understood the container name is host name so it should work.
Does anyone know how to make them communicate? I didnt find any tutorials on internet that wouldnt also dockerize the nginx I DONT WANT IT.

Any help is appretiated

EDIT:
This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.5-buster                                                     
                                                                             
WORKDIR /app                                                                 
                                                                             
ADD . /app                                                                   
                                                                             
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get -y install curl && apt-get install libsasl2$
RUN pip3 install mysqlclient                                                 
RUN pip3 install blinker                                                     
RUN pip3 install pyOpenSSL                                                   
RUN pip3 install uwsgi                                                       
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                         
CMD ["uwsgi", "myproject.ini", "--enable-threads"]
```

UWSGI

```
[uwsgi]                                                                                                                                                             
wsgi-file=wsgi.py                                                                                                                                                   
callable=app                                                                                                                                                        
socket=8081                                                                                                                                                         
module = wsgi:app                                                                                                                                                   
master = true                                                                                                                                                       
processes = 1                                                                                                                                                       
chmod-socket = 666                                                                                                                                                  
vacuum = true                                                                                                                                                       
harakiri = 120                                                                                                                                                      
die-on-term = true
```

**The solution**

1. Change the socket=8081 to socket=0.0.0.0:8081
2. Change the nginx to listen on localhost:8081
3. Add ports 8081:8081 to the docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker has internal DNS server working on `127.0.0.11` inside container. If your nginx is not in container you cannot use it to resolve `myapp` name. Still, you can pick one of those:

1. Make your container listen on host's ports:

```yaml
services:
  myapp:
    ports:  
      # host:container
      - 8081:8081
```

Then reflect this change in your nginx configuration:

```
 location / {
     include    uwsgi_params;
     uwsgi_pass localhost:8081;
 }
```

2. Go back to using unix sockets but this time put socket into host's directory. To do that, first mount host's `/tmp` into container:

```yaml
services:
  myapp:
    volumes:  
      # host:container
      - /tmp:/tmp
```

Then configure your application to put the socket into `/tmp`. The socket will appear in host's `/tmp` and you can configure nginx to communicate to it. You may slightly improve this if you mount not the whole `/tmp` but a single directory inside it. `/tmp/myapp` for example. That way you eliminate chances that your container will mess something with host's files.

Comment: I used the first approach but now the website gives me 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: And the flask app isnt showing that any requests goes to it

Comment: Could you provide results of `docker ps` output?

Comment: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES                    │
ebd43348ade2        ordelogy_monitoringhorndev   "uwsgi myproject.ini…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp   monitoringhorndev

Comment: `0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp` means that port forwarding is in place. Are you sure your app is listening that port and not the unix socket? And if so, whether it is listening on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I will have a look at it thats definitly the problem thanks

Comment: my uwsgi has configured socket=8081                                                                                                                                                        which means it listens on the port if I am correct and the host in flask app is set to 0.0.0.0

Comment: I have added the myproject.ini with uwsgi config to the answer post

Comment: According to https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html `socket` means unix socket, so the app is probably listening on file named 8081 :) . Try using `http-socket` instead.

Comment: Didnt need to change is to http-socket I just edited the socket to socket=0.0.0.0:8081 now the app is running thank you very much man u saved my life

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the whole document myself. Try changing `socket=8081` to `0.0.0.0:8081` instead.